# What is the utility of piping to `/dev/null`?

Tags: stdout, stdin, output, data

Seeing that `/dev/null`'s utility isn't immediately obvious to me, what is the use of `/dev/null` piping?

Comment: Your current user handle.

Comment: Read the wikipedia page on it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/null. But given your username I'm going to assume you already know what it does and are goofing w/ us.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it appears to be a joke.

Comment: It wasn't. You're just not creative.

Comment: You are newbie, read this PDF: http://sourceforge.net/projects/linuxcommand/files/TLCL/13.07/TLCL-13.07.pdf/download

Comment: I don't agree with the close vote. Just because the person asking the question is borderline trolling, doesn't mean the question itself is without merit.

Comment: yeah, I'm on the fence but I'm going to side with @jasonwryan. after all, it's an accepted norm that we take newbie questions (despite our description), and this definitely counts as a newbie question.

Comment: Just FYI, I'm not a troll, I'm eating Kale Krunch and my shoes are $300.

Comment: @SuppressingOutput I said borderline; please refrain from any other inflamatory commenting--it is not helping.

Answer (score 2):

`make >/dev/null`
this will send the normal output to nowhere land, and retain all the errors right in front of you on the screen. Anything basically you don't need to see/have fill your screen you send to `/dev/null`

Answer (score 2):

`/dev/null` is used where input, output, or both are not necessary.  A read will result in zero bytes being returned.  A write will accept any amount of data, and simply discard it.

This is most useful for `cron` jobs where you don't care about the output (or input, as the commands will not be running on an interactive terminal) Or where you want only the exit status of a command without any output.